# Should we burninate the [running] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There's no tag wiki for [running](/questions/tagged/running), and it doesn't appear to serve a single deliberate purpose.

Some different ways it's being used:

- [Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897601/gwt-is-slow-in-development-mode) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496141/how-to-speed-up-matlab-codes) (overlapping sometimes with [performance](/questions/tagged/performance))
- [Issues with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560295/compiling-and-running-java-code-in-sublime-text-2) [compiling and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912522/run-netbeans-project-just-with-ant) [running compiled code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875839/jar-file-keeps-giving-me-could-not-find-the-main-class-program-will-exit)
- [Check if something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742787/check-if-a-specific-exe-file-is-running) [is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142590/how-do-i-detect-if-the-specific-delphi-ide-is-running) [or in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964400/mark-file-for-removal-from-python)

It looks like [running](/questions/tagged/running) is a meta tag: it can't stand alone and it has multiple meanings

Comment: Come on. [running] is basically the only exercise I get.

Comment: +1 - While we are at it, can we ***`also burninate` [run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/run)***. It also serves no purpose aside from getting @Bart exercise :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[running](/questions/tagged/running) is done, and [run](/questions/tagged/run)  [is also burned to the ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252760/burninate-the-run-tag).  Thanks to everyone who pitched in.

Comment: Next up [tag:execute]